# How to get the series' x-axis values into the lower part of the tooltip in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, series

I'd really like to have the year in the tooltip-box appear at the bottom of it, and not at the top. But the use of "point.key" is restricted to the headerFormat only:

```
headerFormat: '{point.key}',
```

How can I integrated this into the pointFormat? Mine looks like this now:

```
 pointFormat: '{series.name}<br />' + '{point.y}<br />' + '(HERE THE YEAR)',
```

Probably there is some nicer way of doing it, perhaps by using a function()-writing? I didn't find something, and my different trials didn't succeed. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/f3rgendb/3/) for this.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you are better off using the [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter). This gives you much more control over every aspect of the layout.

Sample:

```
   tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        useHTML: true,
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        borderColor: '#000000',
        borderRadius: 0,
        formatter: function () {
            return '<div style="color: #000; text-align: center; font-family: Palatino, serif; font-size: 14px; line-spacing: 16px"><b>' +
            this.series.name + '</b><br />' + 
            '<i style="font-size: 12px">' + this.y + 
            '</i><br /><span style="font-size: 12px">(' + this.x + ')</span></div>';
        }
    },
```